# Javascript .map Return

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, array.prototype.map

sampleGroupOfStores is an array of 100 objects

The console logs inside the map show things correct

but console.log(storeResults) is just an array of 100 undefined items

I think I'm not returning things correctly here inside map to make the new array of objects storeResults.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

*i removed any sensitive data from the script below*

I was using .forEach but I decided .map is what I wanted because I want to take sampleGroupOfStores and get a new array of objects out of it based on the criteria in the if statements below.

The setTimeOut was because I was thinking the console.log(storeReults) was running before the map fully finished.

```
const storeResults = sampleGroupOfStores.map( config => {
    exec(config, command, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log('ERROR: Store: ', config.store, ' Message: ', error.level)
            return config.store + error.level
        }
        const mac1 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        const mac2 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        const mac3 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        if(response && mac1 || mac2 || mac3) {
            console.log(config.store, 'MAC PRESENT')
            return config.store + 'MAC PRESENT'
        } else {
            console.log(config.store, 'No MAC PRESENT')
            return config.store + 'No MAC PRESENT'
        }
    })
} )

setTimeout( () => {console.log(storeResults)}, 10000)
```

EDIT:

After some comments I change it to below and I now have some results it's just ugly. I'm working out how to clean it up a bit now so I end up with a new array of objects that include, store number and exec results.

Also this is the NPM for exec https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh-exec

```
const storeResults = sampleGroupOfStores.map( config => {

    const storeInfo = []

    exec(config, command, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            //console.log('ERROR: Store: ', config.store, ' Message: ', error.level)
            storeInfo.push({store: config.store, message: error.level })
        }
        const mac1 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        const mac2 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        const mac3 = _.includes(response, 'MAC ADDRESS')
        if(response && mac1 || mac2 || mac3) {
            //console.log(config.store, 'MAC PRESENT')
            storeInfo.push({store: config.store, message: 'MAC PRESENT'})
        } else {
            //console.log(config.store, 'No MAC PRESENT')
            storeInfo.push({store: config.store, message: 'No MAC PRESENT'})
        }
    })
    return storeInfo
} )

setTimeout( () => {console.log(storeResults)}, 10000)
```

Comment: You are returning object from `exec` function's callback, not `map` function's callback.

Comment: The function you pass to `sampleGroupOfStores.map` doesn't return anything.... anyways, you cannot synchronously map an array and perform an asynchronous call in the map function. You should look into promises and `Promise.all`.

Comment: @theGleep: What do you think `exec` returns?

Comment: Ok, so I need to build like results = [] outside of exec, then inside exec inside the if statements I can push config.store + message or something like that?

Comment: @SirFry only if `exec` is synchronous. If it's asynchronous, what you're trying to do isn't possible, you'll have to return a promise or allow for a callback.

Comment: I added more info to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for exec(), you aren't going to get any value out of it (the result of `exec()` will always be `undefined`

And since that result is what gets passed back out to `map` to be added into the final outcome ... you're getting an array of `undefined`.

It looks like you'll need to re-think your strategy so that you're updating your array from within the callback.

I tend to do as you are considering with `results = []` - and then inside of callback, I use `results.push(usefulValue)`

When you do that, you'll want to stop using `.map()`

`.map()` converts one array to another array by calling a method and building the output array from the responses.

So to change to using an "external" array, you'll want to use a for loop instead of `.map()`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing under EDIT: in the original post I believe. My only problem now is i'm trying to figure out how to build some kind of return that looks good. Right now I'm getting an array with arrays inside it that have an object in it. I think that's because I'm using .push to push an objects. I'm trying to take what is there and format a result to look like.
[
    {
        store: NUM, message: 'message'
    },
    {
        store: NUM, message: 'message'
    },
    {
        store: NUM, message: 'message'
    }
]

Comment: You're still using `.map` - you'll probably want to use `.forEach` instead.  What you're ending up with is an `sampleGroupOfStores.length` copies of storeInfo

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean :( sorry

Comment: ... I'll expand my answer.

Comment: given your current code, it should work if you use storeInfo instead of storeResults.  storeResults is the array built by `.map`, where storeInfo is the array you built using `.push()`

Comment: Ok, so I started playing around more and I ended up getting it to work better with forEach.

Comment: Good! :)  Glad I could help.  It took me a couple of tries before I understood `.map()`  Nowadays I don't know why I ever had a problem with it.